# Find repetition of the same character (alphanumeric) using bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash command to find whether a string contains a repetition of the same alphanumeric character one after another.

For example:

```
input: aaa, abc, aba, abc111;

output: aaa, abc111.
```

"aba" is not considered as a repetition of the same alphanumeric character one after another. "11", "111", "aa", "aaaaaaaaa", etc. are considered as "repetition". Don't worry about input. Assume is has been defined somewhere else as a string.

Say: INPUT="aa"

Comment: How about `aba`? And how do you apply your input? As an argument, as a text?..

Comment: "aba" is not considered as a repetition of the same alphanumeric character one after another. "11", "111", "aa", "aaaaaaaaa", etc. are considered as "repetition". Don't worry about input. Assume is has been defined somewhere else as a string. Say: INPUT="aa"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tr` can help.  (Use the `-s` option that squeezes repeats in the set defined.)

Examples:

```
$ a="abcdef"
$ [ $(echo ${a} | tr -s '[:alnum:]') == "${a}" ] && echo "No repeating characters" || echo "Repeating characters present"
No repeating characters
$ a="abc1111"
$ [ $(echo ${a} | tr -s '[:alnum:]') == "${a}" ] && echo "No repeating characters" || echo "Repeating characters present"
Repeating characters present
$ a="abc123"
$ [ $(echo ${a} | tr -s '[:alnum:]') == "${a}" ] && echo "No repeating characters" || echo "Repeating characters present"
No repeating characters
$ a="aaa123"
$ [ $(echo ${a} | tr -s '[:alnum:]') == "${a}" ] && echo "No repeating characters" || echo "Repeating characters present"
Repeating characters present
$ a="abacdc"
$ [ $(echo ${a} | tr -s '[:alnum:]') == "${a}" ] && echo "No repeating characters" || echo "Repeating characters present"
No repeating characters
```

Comment: Without proper quoting, this will give wrong diagnostics for strings containing multiple spaces or whitespace other than a space.  The fix is easy; use `"$(echo "$a" | ...)"` instead of `$(echo ${a} | ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

in fact the regex matches your targets:

```
'([0-9a-zA-Z])\1'
```

if you want to print those words out, try this:

```
grep -oE '\b\w*([0-9a-zA-Z])\1\w*\b'
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  echo "aaa, abc, aba, abc111"|grep -oE '\b\w*([0-9a-zA-Z])\1\w*\b'
aaa
abc111
```

Comment: Unfortunately, '([0-9a-zA-Z])\1' will also detect "aba" as the repetition; but "aba" is not.

Comment: @RenjuLiu did you try the grep line?

Answer (score 0):

This code would work if you have a set of words in an array:

```
#!/bin/bash

WORDS=(aaa abc aba abc111)

for W in "${WORDS[@]}"; do
    P=''
    for (( I = 0; I < ${#W}; ++I )); do
        C=${W:I:1}
        [[ $C == "$P" ]] && {
            echo "$W"
            break
        }
        P=$C
    done
done
```

Output:

```
aaa
abc111
```